# Python3 and MariaDB using Discord Py

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb, mysql-python, discord.py

I programmed a bot that inserts things into a database off of a users input, and it works great. However, there's times when the database returns multiple of the same strings, and the bot simply uses the first one. What would be the best way of going about this so the user can choose the correct option rather than the bot just using the first choice.

Edit for further clarification:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM forts WHERE name LIKE '" + str(arg) + "%';")
gym_title = str(cursor.fetchall())
```

Sometimes there's multiple of the same that come out, for example, Starbucks. Instead of changing them, I was wondering if I could make it so that the discord bot replies with each one, and the user gets to choose the correct option.

Comment: Could you include the code you're using?

Comment: Details please!!  "database returns" -- via what SQL statement?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?  Do you know about `DISTINCT` and/or `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh

will edit with the code I'm using in a second here to show you what SQL statement I'm using.

Comment: @RickJames i'll edit with the SQL statement I'm using now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually trickier than it sounds, because of `discord.py`'s event driven model.  Our command will accept some argument to our query, and return to the user an itemized list of their choices. We'll store that user and that list in a dictionary.  Then, in our `on_message` event we'll check each message against the dict of authors we care about, and try to interpret their messages as choices in the list until they make a valid selection.

```
waiting_for = {}

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def fort(ctx, arg):
    # database setup stuff
    names = cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM forts WHERE name LIKE '" + str(arg) + "%';")
    if not names:
        await bot.say("That fort does not exist")
    elif len(names) == 1:
        await process_fort(name)
    else:
        choices = "\n".join("{}. {}".format(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(names, start=1))
        await bot.say("Your choices are")
        await bot.say(choices)
        waiting_for[ctx.message.author.id] = names


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    id = message.author.id
    if id in waiting_for:
        if message.content.isdigit():
            names = waiting_for[id]
            selection = int(message.content)
            if 0 < selection < len(names):
                del waiting_for[id]
                await process_fort(name)
                return
    await bot.process_commands(message)

# Whatever you want to do with the name once you have it
async def process_fort(name):
    ...
```

If that seems to complicated, you could also just echo all the possibilities to the user until the enter a query that only returns one result.

Comment: wow, great answer Patrick, really appreciate it! Didn't think about doing it this way for some reason. And this is why I love stackoverflow!

Set as my accepted answer, have a good one Patrick!